# How do I set the x axis continuous that each plot in the graph is scattered relatively

Tags: r, plot, graph

[image]

The left image is my current graph and I would like to make it look like the right one. I'm having two problems. The first is even if I used step in the plot, it doesn't graph the line connecting each dots. The second problem is while the right graph's plots are scattered relatively to the year, mine is scattered proportionally throughout the whole x-axis.

Here is my code
`ggplot() +
    geom_step(data = tbl, mapping = aes(x = tbl$date, y = tbl$size)) +
    geom_point(data = tbl, aes(x = tbl$date, y = tbl$size)) +
    labs(x = 'Data', y = 'Size (Kilobytes)', title = 'stringr: timeline of version sizes')`

I have to somehow convert current date format(yyyy-mm-dd) and change it to just yyyy format but doing that so would make some points to be in the same year. For example, the first three dates I have are 2009-11, 2009-11, and 2010-02 so if I change the format of year, two of them will be on same spot. And I don't know how to figure this out since I am still trying to learn how to use R. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is your data now? You should make `date` a `Date` class object and use `scale_x_date`, and you can specify the format of the labels. See `?scale_x_date` for details.

Comment: As a side note, never put `data$` inside `aes()`. Simple plots will work but it will break complex plots. Just use unquoted column names `aes(x = date, y = size)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes some finagling with the date, but all you should have to do is add a function from the `scales`package to set your x-axis scale. It requires your time to be as class `POSIXct`. Used some dummy data since you didn't post any.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(zoo)
tbl$date <- as.POSIXct(as.yearmon(tbl$date, format = "%Y-%m"))
ggplot() +
  geom_step(data = tbl, mapping = aes(x = date, y = size)) +
  geom_point(data = tbl, aes(x = date, y = size)) +
  labs(x = 'Data', y = 'Size (Kilobytes)', title = 'stringr: timeline of version sizes') +
  scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%Y"))
```

[image: Your desired plot]